# FirebaseDatabase -How to Paginate when using a UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, pagination, uisearchcontroller

As the user types text into the searchBar the `UISearchController` has a delegate method to update search results:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text?.lowercased() else { return }

    Database...usersRef
        .queryOrdered(byChild: "username")
        .queryStarting(atValue: searchText)
        .queryEnding(atValue: searchText+"\u{f8ff}")
        .observe( .childAdded, with: { [weak self](snapshot) in

            let key = snapshot.key

            guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            let user = User(userId: key, dict: dict)
            self?.datasource.append(user)
        })
}
```

That works fine.

When I normally paginate I use this procedure:

```
var startKey: String?

func handlePaginationForPosts() {

    if startKey == nil {

        Database...PostsRef
            .queryOrderedByKey()
            .queryLimited(toLast: 10)
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in

                guard let children = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return }

                if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

                        let postId = child.key

                        if child.key != self?.startKey {

                            guard let dict = child.value as? [String:Any] else { return }

                            let post = Post(postId: postId, dict: dict)

                            self?.datasource.insert(post, at: 0)
                        }
                    }
                    self?.startKey = children.key
                }
            })

    } else {

        let lastIndex = datasource.count

        Database...PostsRef
            .queryOrderedByKey()
            .queryEnding(atValue: startKey!)
            .queryLimited(toLast: 11)
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in

                guard let children = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return }

                if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

                        let postId = child.key

                        if child.key != self?.startKey {

                            guard let dict = child.value as? [String:Any] else { return }

                            let post = Post(postId: postId, dict: dict)
                            // I run a check to make sure the datasource doesn't contain the post before adding it
                            self?.datasource.insert(post, at: lastIndex)
                        }
                    }
                    self?.startKey = children.key
                }
            })
    }
}
```

The problem here is when running a search I use:

```
.queryStarting(atValue: searchText)
.queryEnding(atValue: searchText+"\u{f8ff}")
```

But when paginating a post I use:

```
.queryOrderedByKey()
.queryEnding(atValue: startKey!) ...

self?.datasource.insert(post, at: lastIndex)
```

The `startKey` is the first key in the `snapshot.children.allObjects.first` and the `lastIndex` is the `datasource.count`.

Considering the search query is based on the search text and not a `key`, how can I paginate when I'm already using `.queryEnding(atValue: searchText+"\u{f8ff}")` instead of `.queryEnding(atValue: startKey!)`?

I need to track the key that was pulled from the db so that when I paginate I can run the next set of results from that particular key.

Comment: why not following this? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors, you would use something like `start(afterDocument: lastSnapshot)`

Comment: Hey thanks but that’s for FireStore, I’m using the Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property.

So what you **can** do is filter for the search criteria, and then limit to the firsts N results.

What you **can't** do is filter for the search criteria, skip the first N results, and get the next page.

The closest you can get, and something regularly done for cases such as this, is retrieve the first 2*N results when you need to show page 2. This wastes some bandwidth though, so you'll have to trade that off against how useful the pagination is.

Comment: Hi Frank, I was watching the firestore video and it said that the dev is charged for the amount of data that is pulled. For eg the user is searching the usersRef for a “username” property. The name they enter is “Frank”, 1000 hits might are returned but the frank they’re looking for is the 50th person. If I paginate 10 results, I would’ve only pulled 50 hits to find him. If not then I just paid for 950 other hits that I can’t use. That’s the problem I’m trying to get around. Unless FIRDatabase doesn’t charge me for them like the FireStore does

Comment: I accepted your answer because the way I’m trying to paginate your answer says **it can’t be done**. Thanks.

Comment: Your comment is about Firestore while your question was about the Realtime Database. The billing model is quite different between the two, but you will pay for the additional data loads (and your user will pay for the additional bandwidth if you do this client-side) in both cases. Hence: you'll have to determine how likely your users are to go to subsequent pages vs the extra cost it incurs for you and them.

Comment: Ahhhh, yes that’s the key, i don’t do this client-side because I use .indexOn in my rules. In my comment I wasn’t sure if the billing was the same for both but it seems client-side it is and the data-load is the same for both too. Thanks for the answer 